# How to design and train convolutional neural networks to estimate third band in an image to ful accuracy

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to estimate the third band(Blue) in an RGB image using convolutional neural networks. my design using Keras is a sequentiol model with a convolution2D layer as input layer two hidden layers and output neuron. if i want loss(rmse) to be zero how should i change my model?

my model in python goes like this

```
in_image = skimage.io.imread('test.jpg')[0:50,0:50,:].astype(float)
data = in_image[:,:,0:2]
target = in_image[:,:,2:3]

model1 = keras.models.Sequential()
model1.add(keras.layers.Convolution2D(50,(3,3),strides = (1,1),padding = "same",input_shape=(None,None,2)))  #Convolution Layer
model1.add(keras.layers.Dense(50,activation = 'relu'))                      # Hiden Layer1
model1.add(keras.layers.Dense(50,activation = 'sigmoid'))                      # Hidden Layer 2
model1.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))                                           # Output Layer
adadelta = keras.optimizers.Adadelta(lr=1.0, rho=0.95, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model1.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=adadelta)               # Compile the model


model1.fit(np.array([data]),np.array([target]),epochs = 5000)

estimated_band = model1.predict(np.array([data]))
```

Comment: And what made you think that if loss= 0, it will be a good model?

Answer (score 0):

Given your problem setup, it looks like you're trying to training a neural network on one image such that it is able to predict the blue channel of an image from other 2 images.  Putting aside the use of such an experiment, there are a few important things when training neural networks properly, including.

1. learning rate
2. weight initialization
3. optimizer
4. model complexity.

[Yann Lecun's Efficient backprop](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf) is a late 90s paper that talks about numbers 1, 2 and 3. Number 4 holds on the assumption that as the number of free parameters increase, at some point you'll be able to match each parameter to each output.

Note that achieving zero-loss provides no guarantees on generalization nor does it mean that your model will not generalize, as brilliantly described in a [paper presented at ICLR](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.03530).